# Why do we have mutator methods?

Tags: java, object-oriented, python, language-agnostic

I'm switching from Java to Python and am having trouble understanding the `@Property` decorator. I realized in OOP languages (such as Java) I don't fully understand the point of mutator methods in the following sense:

Say we have a private variable `x`. So we need to make a mutator method

```
public void setX(int val) {
  x = val;
}
```

Now if `x` had been `public` then we could have just did `x = val` and it would have been easier and there would have been no difference. Now in a more complicated scenario, we could add restrictions, perhaps it doesn't make sense for x to be less than 10

```
public void setX(int val) {
  if(x < 10)
    x = 10;
  else
    x = val;
}
```

So in a sense is the point of having mutator methods to impose restrictions on the data? So it's to achieve encapsulation? I'm thinking of this because with Python's `@Property` (correct me if I'm wrong) you're not calling a mutator method but in effect it works the same way in the sense additional logic can happen before the value is changed.

A corolary question is, if we do have such a simple mutator method as in the first example, should the variable just be made public?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't I be using public variables in my Java class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/176876/why-shouldnt-i-be-using-public-variables-in-my-java-class)

Comment: see also: [Are Java's public fields just a tragic historical design flaw at this point?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50225/31260)

Comment: Mutators may not be the best option, as they still expose property details. Properties should be mutated through behaviors (hence the *set* and *get* verb prefixes): https://goo.gl/66O59F. Setters still expose the property (informing other types that there's an `x` property). What if you decide to switch to a `Vector`? Should you expose a `setVector`, cluttering the API? If you exposed a `move` behavior, you'd be able to keep the property info completely hidden, yet still interact with the object as desired (modifying `x` via a behavior that doesn't expose property details)

Answer (score 7):

To answer your last question first - in Java you should always use accessor and mutator methods, because if you make a public field and later decide it needs extra logic - you're gonna have a bad time. If you are lucky and your code is not a library "all" it'll take is cleaning the build product, rebuilding, and going through countless places where you access that variable, changing them by hand. If you are a library - though luck. You're gonna break your users code...

In Python - it doesn't matter. Attribute syntax(and AFAIK implementation) is the same for fields and properties. The only difference is whether your custom method will be called or the default `__getattribute__`/`__setattribute__` which will look inside the `__dict__`(or set a value in it). So if you don't need the extra logic - just use a regular field. You can always change it later.

As for the "why" - the most common reason for using a `@property` in Python is that you don't store the actual , direct value inside the object.

For example:

```
class Vector2D(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def length(self):
        return (self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2) ** 0.5

    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        multiplier = value / self.length
        self.x *= multiplier
        self.y *= multiplier
```

We don't store the `length` directly - we only store `x` and `y`. But we can still get and set the length like it was an ordinary property - and our `@property` code does the work behind the scenes for us.

Comment: *If you are lucky and your code is not a library "all" it'll take is cleaning the build product, rebuilding, and going through countless places where you access that variable, changing them by hand.* .... Or put the cursor in the field declaration, alt+shift+r, select "encapsulate field" from the menu, then press enter s couple of times. (This is for eclipse... Other ides may have different sequences)

Answer (score 2):

As stated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594120/python-read-only-property

I've also seen the `@property` decorator used to signify that a field is "read-only". For example:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path = path

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path
```

Of course, we're all consenting adults in Python and this isn't actually read-only, but you won't be able to assign through the `path` property, only through the `_path` field.